# Insertion in HashMap vs Hashset

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashset

In the case of `HashMap`,it replaces the old value with the new one in case of key duplication.In the case of `HashSet`, the item isn't inserted at all. Since `HashSet` is implementing `HashMap` internally. Why are these two insertions handled differently?

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges here.  `HashMap`s work like `Map`s, and `HashSet`s work like `Set`s. `Map`s and `Set`s are two entirely different concepts, and you shouldn't let the fact that a `HashSet` might be implemented on top of a `HashMap` lead you to believe otherwise.

Comment: You're confusing yourself with bad phrasing. *"HashMap replaces the old Key value"* is correct/incorrect. It replaces the old *value*, but the *key* is unchanged. A `HashSet` is actually implemented as a `HashMap`, where the *value* is ignored, i.e. any value added to the `Set` is put into the map as a *key* with a dummy value: `public boolean add(E e) { return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null; }`

Comment: So can i rephrase it as both the "Duplicate Key in HashMap" and "Duplicate Value in HashSet" wouldn't overwrite the previous ones and would return false as soon it finds a duplicate key(HashMap) or value(HashSet).

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` is replaces old **value** with a new one, when you are inserting it with the same key.
Example:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "first put");
System.out.println(map.get(1)); // <-- prints `first put`
map.put(1, "second put");
System.out.println(map.get(1)); // <-- prints `second put`
```

So basically when the new value arrives with a key already present in the map, it just replaces the value for this key, because even if the key is the same, new value can be different from the one associated with this key in the map.

In case of the `HashSet`, there is only **key**, there is no value. So when already existing `key` arrives, there is noting to do, it is already there.

Regarding internal implementation of the `HashSet`, indeed it uses `HashMap` internally, but what it does, it just create one `object`:

```
// Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
```

and when you `add` some `key` to set, it just calls `put(key, present)` on this map, using the same object for all entries(in order not to allocate lots of useless objects:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

So all in all, indeed `HashSet`uses internally `HashMap`, and when you put something to hash map, new value is always assigned instead of the old one, however the `key` isn't, and as `HashSet` uses its keys as the keys in HashMap, then if you put duplicate key in `HashSet` it wouldn't remove the old one.
Example:

Lets assume we have some entity class which has 2 fields, int `id`, and string `name`, but only `id` participates in `equals` method implementation.

```
    Entity entity1 = new Entity(1, "some name");
    Entity entity2 = new Entity(1, "some other name");
    System.out.println(entity1.equals(entity2)); // returns true

    Map<Integer, Entity> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(entity1.id, entity1);
    map.put(entity2.id, entity2);
    System.out.println(map.get(entity1.id).name); // returns "some other name"

    Map<Entity, String> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
    keyMap.put(entity1, entity1.name);
    keyMap.put(entity2, entity2.name);
    System.out.println(keyMap.keySet()); // returns [Entity{id=1, name='some name'}]
    System.out.println(keyMap.values()); // returns [some other name]

    Set<Entity> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(entity1);
    set.add(entity2);
    System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(set)); // returns [Entity{id=1, name='some name'}]
```

Also you shouldn't rely on that too, as its internal implementation details which can be changed in future releases, `HashMap` and `HashSet` use `equals` methods the check if the object is the same. If you have an two objects which `equals` returns `true` but you still want to treat the differently, most probably there is some problem in you Entity design, however there are rare cases when inded thats the desired effect, in such cases you can take a look at the `IdentityHashMap`.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation!
Just one question though, would the duplicate Key value be overwritten from the previous one or it will return as soon it finds the duplicate.

Comment: @AnkushDutt as I mention this `PRESENT` object is static, meaning that all instances of `HashSet` would put this particular instance of Object as a value to underlying map, when you will call `add` on the `HashSet`, from the current implementation of `HashMap` I see that indeed it will reassign new value  even if they are equal, but you shouldnt rely on it, as its the internal implementation details. However the `key` wouldn't be reassigned if its already present. If it matters to you which object was assigned, even if they are equal, then you should probably take a look at `IdentityHashMap`

Comment: @AnkushDutt I updated answer with some more explanation and examples

Comment: So can i rephrase it as both the "Duplicate Key in HashMap" and "Duplicate Value in HashSet" wouldn't overwrite the previous ones and would return false as soon it finds a duplicate key(HashMap) or value(HashSet).

Comment: @AnkushDutt yes, in case of `HashSet` key wouldn't be overwritten, in `HashMap` key wouldn't be overwritten too, however value would be. You can check last example in my answer, it shows this behaviour for all case